# Shopify's `min/maxVariantPrice` filtering doesn't work as expected

Tags: shopify, shopify-storefront-api

When I run the following query:

```
products(first:10, query:"priceRange:{minVariantPrice:10, }") {
  edges {
    node {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to see all products whose variant price is greater than 10, but instead, it returns nothing.

I have a product whose variant price is 15, if I replace 10 with 15 in the above query I see that product as result. Isn't it supposed to show up in the first query as well?

Answer (score 4):

Your query is wrong, the GraphQL request just ignores the query at the moment.

If you want to check the variants price you need to use `variants.price` so your query should become something like so:

```
{
  products(first:10, query:"variants.price:>10") {
  edges {
    node {
      title
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The schema does not show variants as a query attribute.

Comment: Reference: https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/common-objects/queryroot#products-2020-10.

Comment: @DavidLazar It does, check above link.

Comment: Oh. Storefront API.. sorry. Was working off the Admin one,. Oops. My bad.

Comment: This is a great answer but I'm curious as to how you found out about it. So much of Shopify's documentation is either incomplete or outright incorrect, I could not find any example code which matches this (but it works).

Comment: @RossAngus if you are referring to the `:>` there is a documentation about the query and how the search syntax works here: https://shopify.dev/api/usage/search-syntax The `variants.price` itself is listed in here as available query argument: https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/reference/common-objects/queryroot

Comment: Thanks, @drip. That's useful.